Android 11 - Push notification icon problem (Firebase messaging)
I am working on a Flutter project which has a notification feature. Everything works well except that the notification icon is not showing properly. I am testing on 2 devices: Android 13 and Android 11, and the Android 13 works perfectly on both notification center and status bar after I added the below code to AndroidManifest.xml. It's just when I am testing on Android 11, the notification icon just shows on the status and uses the app icon / launcher icon as the icon. Can any one know how would this happened? Is it that the below code cannot support in Andorid 11? I tried to googled related post, but all of them just ask to use the code below...
<application
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</application>

